# Distance between pairs of coordinastes (UTM) in km with R

Tags: r, coordinates, distance, r-sf, utm

I have a dataframe with 2 pairs of UTM (32N) coordinates and I need to compute the differences in km   between each of them, from origin to destination.
I'm trying with sf library, using "by_element" but I obtain an error message "Error in st_distance(data, by_element = TRUE) : !missing_y non è TRUE".
What's wrong?
If I use it without the "by_element" option, it works and the distance matrix between all coordinates is created, but this is not what I need.

```
library(sf)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), x_origin = c(642683.2, 373775,383881 ), y_origin = c(5082920, 4997274,4994504), x_dest =c(642683.3, 1126050,942763.9 ), y_dest=c(5082920, 4374481,4534235  )) 

data <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("x_origin", "y_origin"), crs="4326" )

distances <- st_distance(data, by_element = TRUE  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have provided `x` (origin) to `st_distance()`but no `y` (destination).
And that CRS can't be right, sf doesn't recognise EPSG code if it's a string and 4326 would suggest coordinates are in WGS84 lat/long. Assuming 32632, WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N.

```r
library(sf)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), x_origin = c(642683.2, 373775,383881 ), y_origin = c(5082920, 4997274,4994504), x_dest =c(642683.3, 1126050,942763.9 ), y_dest=c(5082920, 4374481,4534235  )) 
origin <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("x_origin", "y_origin"), crs=32632 )
dest <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("x_dest", "y_dest"), crs=32632 )

(distances <- st_distance(origin, dest,  by_element = TRUE ))
#> Units: [m]
#>        1        2        3 
#>      0.1 976621.1 724015.0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. 4326 was the indication I found in the metadata but here I see why it is uncorrect. I assumed also that what was not origin was destination, getting it wrong

Answer (score 1):

First, `sf` can't know that you are calculating distances between origin and destination by the way you have input the data.
Second, the EPSG code for UTM Zone 32N is not `4326`.
Third, you should have used `crs = st_crs(4326)` instead of `crs = "4326"`.

Use the following piece of code to create the objects needed to calculate the distances you are interested in

```
library(sf)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3),
                 x_origin = c(642683.2, 373775, 383881),
                 y_origin = c(5082920, 4997274, 4994504),
                 x_dest = c(642683.3, 1126050, 942763.9),
                 y_dest = c(5082920, 4374481, 4534235))

origin <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("x_origin", "y_origin"),
                   crs = st_crs(32632))
dest <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("x_dest", "y_dest"),
                 crs = st_crs(32632))
```

> Note the different EPSG code for the CRS.

Next, we calculate the distances (the default of this projection is in meters)

```
distances <- st_distance(origin, dest, by_element = TRUE)
```

> If you use `by_element = FALSE`, you get all the pairwise distances.

Lastly, we can use the package `units` to convert the distances to `km` (or we can simply divide them by 1000).

```
units::set_units(distances, "km")
> Units: [km]
> [1]   0.0001 976.6211 724.0150
```

Comment: @Icgodoy Thanks. How do we know default is in meters instead of km?

Comment: @ggg: e.g. from the [wkt2 string](https://epsg.io/32632): `LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]`.